# What would be the proper way to use flag-icon-css in a Symfony project?

Tags: css, symfony, vendor

All is in the title.
I want to use [flag-icon-css](https://github.com/lipis/flag-icon-css) in my twig view.
There is no instruction about composer and I don't know how to use grunt or bower. 
I have feeling that I should put the package in the vendor repertory but from here I have no idea what to do to have this line working :

```
<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-gr"></span>
```

Comment: `web/` is your public directory, the only directory accessible by the web browser. Apart from that, it's just how you would use it everywhere else, Symfony is only about the back-end stuff

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alternatively, you can install my simple [bundle](https://packagist.org/packages/st/flagiconcss-bundle) for your task, works without grunt or bower. You can install and use it like this (also here is a [README file](https://github.com/xurshid29/STFlagIconCssBundle/blob/master/README.md), with full description of installation):

1. add `"st/flagiconcss-bundle": "~1.0"` to your `composer.json` file, and run `composer update`
2. register the bundle in AppKernel.php file (add `new ST\FlagIconCssBundle\STFlagIconCssBundle()` to the `bundles` array in the `registerBundles` method of `AppKernel.php` file)
3. run `app/console assets:install web`
4. include the bundle's css file to your template file: `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ asset('bundles/stflagiconcss/css/flag-icon.min.css') }}" />`

Comment: Excellent ! This is exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 3):

for Symfony 3 works for me:

1. download https://github.com/lipis/flag-icon-css/archive/master.zip, contains folder flag-icon-css-master, unzip somewhere, e.g. folder tmp/
2. copy file flag-icon.css (or flag-icon.min.css) from flag-icon-css-master/css into your symfony project web/css
3. copy folder flag (flag-icon-css-master/flag) into your symfony project/web
4. in your symfony project, e.g. app/Resources/views/base.html.twig, add:

`{% block stylesheets %}
...
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/flag-icon.css') }}" />
...
{% endblock %}`

5. in your templates use e.g.:

`<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-gr"></span>`